# Checking specific numbers in a list Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to find if values in a list are less then or equal to 1, and then count them. My issue is I don't know how to check lists for specific values. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
xylist = [distance(a,b) for a,b in zip(randomlistx,randomlisty)]
```

Where in the list are up to 1 million randomly generated numbers, some which are less then 1 and some which are greater.

I have tried using for loops, and counters but that didn't work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a generator expression to sum. If the generated sequence is made up of booleans, then the true values count as 1, so `sum` acts as a count.

```
sum(x<=1 for x in xylist)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! I thought the sum added the numbers inside the list but I guess not.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
sum(x < 1 for x in xylist)
```

Comment: You don't need a list

Comment: It's not a list comprehension any more.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know, but you left in the phrase "Try a list comprehension"

Comment: Removed the note about 'list comprehension'.  Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Your answer and khelwood's answer worked thank you! I was going to try this but I figured it would add the numbers like another poster commented. I was wrong I guess, this works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Working with numpy arrays would sometimes be easier on large numerical lists:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(list)
sum(arr < 1)
```